# MVC Error on ID as Primary Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, key

I am new to C# and Razor, and I having some trouble with `Id` as primary key (using EF). I am setting `(Is Identity)` as off and I want to record some random number for the field, but it keeps giving me an error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

When I set `id` as `nvarchar` it is ok, or if I set another field as primary key for example `Name` (`nvarchar`) then `id` (`int`) works, but once again I need to keep it as primary key. So if someone can help. Thanks guys.

Comment: How is the `ID` defined in your database? If it's a `INT IDENTITY` in your SQL Server database, then you **cannot** set its value yourself - you must let the database handle that for you

Answer (score 0):

Because updating a primary key in your table is never a good idea, you want this field to be excluded from you MVC app and have it autogenerated instead.